# LinkedIn API V2

Tags: laravel, linkedin-api

I have used the laravel package for "\Artesaos\LinkedIn". The LinkedIn V1 is worked properly. But, the LinkedIn V2 version is not working using laravel package.

When I tried the below code. It returns "Not enough permissions to access: GET /me" error response.

Please, anyone, assist me?

Request:

```
 $tokenResponse = LinkedIn::setAccessToken(token);

 $result = LinkedIn::get('v2/me'); 

 if(!empty($result)) {

    print_r($result);
 }
```

Response:

```
Array ( [serviceErrorCode] => 100 [message] => Not enough permissions to access: GET /me [status] => 403 )
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles. “LinkedIn API V2” doesn’t actually point to _anything_ to do with your specific problem.

Comment: Laravel package with LinkedIn API V2.

I am facing some challenge to integrate the LinkedIn API (V2). 

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Now, the "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json" is not working at all.

Please advise?

Comment: There is an open github issue to update the artesaos/laravel-linkedin library to LinkedIn v2 APIs: https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client/issues/167

Comment: When i was update the API code then i received below response. Please advise

"Array ( [serviceErrorCode] => 100 [message] => Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/format] [status] => 403 )"

Comment: The error seems to be self-explanatory; unpermitted fields in parameter mean that you are either making an API request with some missing parameters or you are not passing the right scopes in the call. Kindly provide the full URL for the GET request and the scopes you are using in the call.

Comment: Thanks. I got a solution